# App Store Connect: create my own discount subscription instead of using promotional offers

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, revenuecat

I would like to have full control on the discount rate I want to apply. I mean I want to select if this user can benefit the discount. Using the introductory offer in app store connect, I am not sure I can select from my server to which user and at which rate I can propose this offer, and plus the offer are limited in time and have a specific duration.

**Do you think it's valid from App Store POV that I create my own subscriptions with my discount rates ?**

For example, I will have premium_subscription for 100/month, then premium_subscription_15 for 85/month, premium_subcription_25 for 75/month and so on... Using this way, my server will uses criteria of the user (basic/intensive usage, level, age...) to set the right subscription offer, and I can email him before to inform about the discount rate.

Another constraint, I use revenuecat as a gateway for subscription.

Many thanks.